# Creating an application with wxPython where I could navigate across several pages

Tags: wxpython

I would like to create an application built with wxPyhton where I could navigate across several pages with two next and previous buttons.

Can you give me real codes examples?

Answer (score 1):

What you are likely looking for is a wizard. There are several pages on the wxPython website that talk about how to create one:

- https://wiki.wxpython.org/wxWizard
- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.adv.Wizard.html?highlight=wizard

I have also written on the topic on my blog. You can see how to roll your own wizard [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/12/wxpython-how-to-create-a-generic-wizard/) or create one using the widget that wxPython provides [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/27/wxpython-a-wizard-tutorial/).

Here's a short example:

```
import wx
import wx.wizard as wiz

########################################################################
class TitledPage(wiz.WizardPageSimple):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        """Constructor"""
        wiz.WizardPageSimple.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        title = wx.StaticText(self, -1, title)
        title.SetFont(wx.Font(18, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
        sizer.Add(title, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE|wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(wx.StaticLine(self, -1), 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    """"""
    wizard = wx.wizard.Wizard(None, -1, "Simple Wizard")
    page1 = TitledPage(wizard, "Page 1")
    page2 = TitledPage(wizard, "Page 2")
    page3 = TitledPage(wizard, "Page 3")
    page4 = TitledPage(wizard, "Page 4")

    wx.wizard.WizardPageSimple.Chain(page1, page2)
    wx.wizard.WizardPageSimple.Chain(page2, page3)
    wx.wizard.WizardPageSimple.Chain(page3, page4)
    wizard.FitToPage(page1)

    wizard.RunWizard(page1)

    wizard.Destroy()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    main()
    app.MainLoop()
```